# Use print return values like return values

Tags: python, python-3.x, return-value

I have a small problem that involves treating print values like return values. For example, say I have a program that manipulates a string:

```
def someprogram(x):
    answers=input()
    #some manipulation, say, depending on input
    print(x)
    moreanswers=input()
    #some more manipulation depending on input
    print(x)
```

And this cycle repeats several times. And say I want to make another program that interacts with this program by taking the print values. Using the `pyautogui` module or otherwise, it types the input, depending on the print values.

Note that what I'm really trying to do is that I have a program that guesses a number that you're thinking of, each time printing the guess. I want to create a program that plays with the first program, replying using `pyautogui`. Is there a module, method, function, or otherwise, that I can use? I'm not really asking for someone to write the whole program for me, just a way I can get around this problem.

To my knowledge, the only way to do this is using return values.

Comment: Have you considered using functions to return the values?  Maybe make an api for the second program to consume.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What's wrong with returning the values?

Comment: @T It's kind of troublesome modifying the first program. Also, the first program prints multiple times, which I don't believe can be done with return. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: If you want to keep the printing behavior as-is but save those values in another scope (global, a different function, different script, etc.) just return the values to whatever scope called it, with e.g. `return answers, moreanswers`. This is the fundamental purpose of functions.

Comment: You can also turn the function into a generator and `yield` multiple results. Not that I recommend this but you could consider temporarily changing `sys.stdout` to a `StringIO` object and then you would have all the prints in a str buffer which you could get with `StringIO.getvalue()`

Comment: A generator with a string buffer would be cool, but I think it might be better for the OP to learn the basic usage of `return` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def someprogram(b):
answers=input()
#some manipulation, say, depending on input
return ans
```

## Here the ans will be saved in var

```
def newf(a)
moreanswers=input()
#some more manipulation depending on input
return ans2
```

var=someprogram(x)
var2=newf(var)

## Here the ans of 1st function that was saved in var using return command is now put in second function i.e you are using ans of first function in second function!